# Windows connection limit

Tags: windows, tcpip

Windows XP is said to have a connection limit. There are some patches that increase this limit to 100 or higher.  I was just wondering if my download speed (from torrents, etc.) or number of simultaneous downloads depend on it?

Comment: Hello! SU is for acquiring answers to questions about actual problems. Please see the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq#dontask) for more info.

Comment: XP actually limits the number of **half open** connections.  This is a common myth. Another common myth is XP limits the number of SMB connections to 10. SMB != TCPIP connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This connection limit, limits the amount of connections your computer can have, so, if you get lucky and find a peer with very high upload speed, you will not be affected - but - in most situations, it will affect torrent speed.

If you do a lot of torrenting, I recommend you apply the patch.

For everyday non peer to peer work, it is unlikely you will benefit from this patch.